# Error: response is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-maps

See my code below. I get the following error :

> Error: response is not defined, this happenes in the
>
> ```
> distanceInput.value = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value;
> ```

(it should be working but it's not)

I searched quite a long time now, can anybody please help me?
thanks in advance

Distance Calculator

```
<style type="text/css">      
    #map_canvas 
    {        height: 100px;      
             }
 </style>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=false"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        var directionDisplay;  
        var map;    
        function initialize() {    
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();    
            var melbourne = new google.maps.LatLng(-37.813187, 144.96298);    
            var myOptions = {      
            zoom:12,      
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,      
            center: melbourne
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        }
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        function calcRoute() {
            var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
            var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
            var request = {
            origin:start,
            destination:end,
            travelMode:google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });
        var distanceInput = document.getElementById("distance");
        distanceInput.value = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value; 
        }
    </script>  
 </head>  
 <body onload="initialize()">    
    <div>     
        <p>        
          <label for="start">Start: </label>        
          <input type="text" name="start" id="start" />        
          <label for="end">End: </label>        
          <input type="text" name="end" id="end" />        
          <input type="submit" value="Calculate Route" onclick="calcRoute()" />      
        </p>      
        <p>        
          <label for="distance">Distance (km): </label>        
          <input type="text" name="distance" id="distance"/>      
        </p>    
    </div>    
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>  
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

`response` would not exist until the callback gets called, so try setting it inside callback of `directionsService.route`, like:

```
...
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
   if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      var distanceInput = document.getElementById("distance");
      distanceInput.value = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value; 
   }
});        
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Because **`response`** is out of scope.  So you have to move then inside **`directionsService.route`** method.

```
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
     if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            var distanceInput = document.getElementById("distance");
            distanceInput.value = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value; 
       }
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/er4s3/1/)